# How to fire VACUUM command using shell script in postgres

Tags: shell, psql

Here is my shell script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    psql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --dbname=SIEM --username=dbauser
    vacuumdb --analyze --verbose --table 'vuln' SIEM
```

but its not working fine and gives error as:

```
   linux-lxh4:/home/gaurav # ./script.sh 
   psql (9.2.5)
   Type "help" for help.

   SIEM=# \q
   vacuumdb: could not connect to database root: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "root"
```

Edit1:I used this code :

```
   psql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --dbname=SIEM --username=dbauser
   VACUUM FULL VERBOSE vuln
```

And here is error:

```
   ./script.sh: line 4: VACUUM: command not found
```

Comment: When my brains memory works, vacuumdb is a process for postgres databases that is configured to be called in a regular schedule somewhere near the database configuration.

Comment: can you please correct my script to fire vacuum command using this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Postgres VACUUM documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-vacuum.html)

the administrative command is called `vacuum` not `vacuumdb`.

I don't have a psql here but it should be

```
#!/bin/bash
psql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --dbname=SIEM --username=dbauser
-c 'VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE vuln'
```

Comment: VACUUM FULL VERBOSE vuln

Answer (score 5):

No need to connect to Postgres using psql if you're running vacuumdb later. Instead use something like the following:

```
  vacuumdb --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --dbname=SIEM --username=dbauser --analyze --verbose --table 'vuln'
```

(alternatively as mentioned in another answer, you can use the VACUUM SQL command after connecting using psql. The syntax is different and does not use "--xxxx" options)

Answer (score 3):

The bash script that we are using here in OLA to vacuum reportsdb.

```
                     #!/bin/sh
                     dbname="reportsdb_new"
                     username="postgres"
                     psql $dbname $username << EOF
                     vacuum FULL VERBOSE ANALYZE ;
                     reindex database reportsdb_new ;
                     EOF
```